# Redshift: Is there a limit on number of CASE statements?

Tags: case, amazon-redshift

I have a query with 4 CASE statements each having 35 WHEN expressions, that is throwing a run time error (code: 14001, message: Query compilation failed for /rds/bin/padb.1.0.7152/data/). The explain plan doesn't show any errors.

However, when I reduce the total number of case statements to 82 by commenting a few, the query runs fine.

Is there a maximum limit on the number of case statements in redshift?

I'm currently using the query by commenting some statements that are not necessary right now but might be in future, so need a more elegant solution to this issue.

Would appreciate any help here. Thanks!

Comment: You could try nesting CASE like: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0d3b84a85af42e8b5a49a9631b11e852

Comment: If you need 140 CASE statements you should rethink your design. The *real* solution is to fix the design, not try to add even more statements. What does the query look like? Why not eg join with lookup or dimension tables to replace values with others?

Comment: Lookups will probably be a lot faster than CASE statements too. Instead of evaluating the `CASE` statement for each row (called RBAR - Row By Agonizing Row), Redshift will be able to use indexes to match main and lookup rows and return just the data needed.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  My query has 4 CASE statements, each with 35 WHEN expressions. @PanagiotisKanavos - could you please share any example links on how to use Lookups?  Will evaluate and see if it is a better solution for my query.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda thanks for the suggestion, but each case statement is a separate column in my query so I can't use nesting.